# Bootstrap CSS to set groups of grid rows to 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a webpage with HTML & CSS, using the bootstrap framework. It is based on the grid layout system. I would like to have my `navbar` and first row of my grid in a group and the second row in a group, where each group fills 100% of the screen height. I can't see how a div definition would work as it spans the middle of two div classes. How do I do this?

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav links">
        <li><a href="#">About<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>/li>
        <li><a href="#">Pre-Order</a></li>
        <img src="Images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:auto; height:75px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="container-fluid"></div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-1">.col-md-1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">.col-md-8</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Off topic: An image is not a valid child of a list element.

Comment: Did you intend for your container element to be empty? I formatted your code to see it better.

Comment: @isherwood no, thanks for pointing out! I have tried using the calc method to offset the height of the banner, but it isn't working for me? Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fa4rsueb/2/), can you see any issues?